# List of iOS applications that support Mirror Display

Tags: objective-c, ios, mirroring

Is it possible to find out (programmatically) which iOS applications installed on the device (iPad) support Mirror Display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Apps live in a sandbox and other apps can know nothing about them.

Comment: It's true, what you said about sandbox. But we can communicate with applications if they have url schemes defined. So, i was wondering if this information can be retrieved via any such method?

Comment: URL scheme can only open an app. The app you open will not communicate back to your app.